# Why do these two Highcharts calls produce different windrose charts

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

Below is an html file that has the ability to create a wind rose chart with the same exact data and attributes. The problem is, there are two calls to create wind rose charts `new Highcharts.StockChart(commonOptions)` and `Highcharts.chart('container')`. If you look at both of the charts, you can see they create different charts (mainly in how tooltips are displayed). The first call displays all the tooltips and the same time while the second call creates normal tooltips. There must be some option(s) that causes this but after many hours have not been able to find it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {

    var categories = ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW'];
    var commonOptions = {
       chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        polar: true,
        type: 'column'
      },
      xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        tickInterval: 22.5,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return categories[parseInt(this.value / 22.5)] ;
          }
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        endOnTick: false,
        reversedStacks: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          shadow: false,
          groupPadding: 0,
          pointPlacement: 'on'
        }
      },
  rangeSelector: {enabled:false},
  navigator: {enabled: false},
    scrollbar: {enabled: false},
        series: [{ name:"a",
        data: [{x: 0, y: 5}, {x: 22.5,y: 3}, {x: 45,y: 4}, {x: 67.5, y: 2}, {x: 90,y: 9}, {x: 112.5, y: 2}, {x: 135,y: 8}, {x: 157.5,y: 9}, {x: 180,y: 2}]}, {
        name:"b",
        data: [{x: 0,y: 2}, {x: 22.5,y: 6}, {x: 45,y: 1}, {x: 67.5,y: 9}, {x: 90,y: 9}, {x: 112.5,y: 3}, {x: 135,y: 5}, {x: 157.5,y: 3}, {x: 180,y: 7}]}, {
        name:"C",
        data: [{x: 0,y: 5}, {x: 22.5,y: 3}, {x: 45,y: 4}, {x: 67.5, y: 2}, {x: 90,y: 9}, {x: 112.5,y: 2}, {x: 135,y: 8}, {x: 157.5,y: 9}, {x: 180,y: 2}]}]

    var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(commonOptions);
    });

    Highcharts.chart('container1', {
      chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'column'
      },
      xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        tickInterval: 22.5,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return categories[this.value / 22.5];
          }
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        endOnTick: false,
        reversedStacks: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          shadow: false,
          groupPadding: 0,
          pointPlacement: 'on'
        }
      },
  rangeSelector: {enabled:false},
  navigator: {enabled: false},
    scrollbar: {enabled: false},
      series: [{ name:"a",
        data: [{x: 0, y: 5}, {x: 22.5,y: 3}, {x: 45,y: 4}, {x: 67.5, y: 2}, {x: 90,y: 9}, {x: 112.5, y: 2}, {x: 135,y: 8}, {x: 157.5,y: 9}, {x: 180,y: 2}]}, {
        name:"b",
        data: [{x: 0,y: 2}, {x: 22.5,y: 6}, {x: 45,y: 1}, {x: 67.5,y: 9}, {x: 90,y: 9}, {x: 112.5,y: 3}, {x: 135,y: 5}, {x: 157.5,y: 3}, {x: 180,y: 7}]}, {
        name:"C",
        data: [{x: 0,y: 5}, {x: 22.5,y: 3}, {x: 45,y: 4}, {x: 67.5, y: 2}, {x: 90,y: 9}, {x: 112.5,y: 2}, {x: 135,y: 8}, {x: 157.5,y: 9}, {x: 180,y: 2}]}]
    });
    }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 420px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        <div id="container1" style="min-width: 420px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *If you look at the two charts you can see...* You didn't provide any snippet or fiddle how can we see anything ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gn4c1sdv/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you add split:false to the first chart's tooltip section, then they both will display tooltips the same

Answer (score 0):

That differences result from the fact that you used two different chart constructor type:

```
Highcharts.stockChart([renderTo], options);

Highcharts.chart([renderTo], options);
```

> Highstock is based on Highcharts, meaning it has all the core functionality of Highcharts, plus some additional features.

In addition, some of the default options (for example `tooltip.split` or `legend.enabled`) are different in these chart types.

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nsy8rdg6/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.html#.stockChart

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.html#.chart

**Docs:**

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/understanding-highstock